# I want to load a .cube file and perform lut (look up table) operation on the bitmap, how should I do it?

Tags: android, filter, lookup-tables

I want to load a .cube file and perform lut (look up table) operation on the bitmap, how should I do it?I have tried many methods, but can't achieve the effect.Below is part of my .cube file, which is in the assets folder. I'm an Android developer. Thank you very much!
LUT_3D_SIZE 16

0.047547 0.047530 0.047452
0.048402 0.047617 0.047506
0.049965 0.047724 0.047577
0.053374 0.047850 0.047734
0.123526 0.048112 0.052582
0.246398 0.048146 0.061750
0.414042 0.048312 0.074718
0.564678 0.048498 0.086391
0.675568 0.048692 0.094992
0.753911 0.048893 0.101159
0.811007 0.049099 0.105664
0.852993 0.049313 0.108994
0.886038 0.049539 0.111543

I tried RenderScript, ColorMatrix and pixel replacement of the bitmap. I parsed the .cube into a one-dimensional Float memory. I don't know if it is correct. I wish there was a way to load the .cube file correctly so that it could work correctly with the bitmap.